# Why doesn't this kotlin code throw out-of-bounds errors?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, kotlin

This is a `sort` function for an array - `elements`. After we add an item to the right of the `elements`, we call `sort` on it.

```
    sort() {
    var index = elements.size - 2
    while (index >= 0 &&
    elements[index + 1].compareTo(elements[index]) > 0) {
    swap(index, index + 1)
    index--;
    }
    }
```

Suppose I have this array: `val array = ArrayList()`. Now I add 1 to this `array` and every time I add an item I run `sort` on `array`. Cleary, we have:

```
    index = -1
    elements[1].compareTo(elements[-1])
```

The code compiles and runs correctly. I think that the biggest index == elements.size - 1 and the second largest == elements.size - 2, so I modified the code like this:

```
    sort() {
            var index = count
            while (index >= 0 &&
                elements[index - 1].compareTo(elements[index - 2]) > 0) {
                swap(index-1, index - 2)
                index--;
            }
```

Here's the error: "Index -1 out of bounds for length 1"

My questions:

1. What's the point of `var index = elements.size - 2`, taking away 2.
2. An out of bounds error in the second piece of code and not the original although both access array elements out of their bounds.

Update: This is my own modification, so I do not know if it reflects the intent of the author.

```
    sort(elements: ArrayList<Int>) {
    fun swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
        val tmp = elements[i]
        elements[i] = elements[j]
        elements[j] = tmp
      }
        var index = elements.size - 2
        while (index >= 0 &&
          elements[index + 1].compareTo(elements[index]) > 0) {
          swap(index, index + 1)
          index--;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code you posted doesn't even compile. There are so many things missing here.

Comment: The source code is here: https://github.com/raywenderlich/dsk-materials/tree/editions/2.0/13-priority-queue/projects/challenge/src/main/kotlin

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. I should not need to visit an external site to see your [mcve].

Comment: It's part of all of those files. Anyway, I've figured out why index = count - 2. I just don't know why out-of-bounds indexes are not allowed, but they are allowed at run time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly missed this check:

`while (index >= 0`

No, original code did not go out of bounds, because it didn't execute the code inside the loop for `index = -1`. Your code does and then it goes out of bounds. I didn't verify this, but I guess if you would modify this check as well as other places, so it would be: `while (index >= 2` then your code would be fine.

The reason to subtract 2 is just to start sorting from the element that is second from the end. And inherently, it ignores empty and single-item arrays.

Also, it doesn't really look like a fully working sorting algorithm. It looks like a bubble sort, but you need to run this code several times in another loop.